# Troubleshooting "Connection closed by authenticating user andy 173.63.60.32 port 11706 [preauth]"

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, unix, putty

As noted in the title, I am having trouble connecting to a remote server through ssh.
I am trying to connect a Windows machine to a server running CentOS. I have been using PuTTY on the Windows machine to try and connect.

Initially when it wasn't working the error on PuTTY said that the server did not recognize the public key being used. I then double checked that the public key was added to `~/.ssh/authorized_users` the way I thought it should be and noticed that the key looked different than the keys I was used to, and discovered that is was in a different format (starting with `---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----`). I then got the public key into the format I am used to seeing for unix-like ssh (with `ssh-rsa` at the beginning). I then restarted sshd and tried again - no luck.

After that I looked around at a few different posts from users with similar issues from across the stack network and elsewhere, and tried a few more changes to make it work, including:

1. These steps from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/306798/trying-to-do-ssh-authentication-with-key-files-server-refused-our-key#:%7E:text=chmod%20700%20%7E/.ssh,USER%20%7E/.ssh%20%2DR):

   - `chmod 700 ~/.ssh`
   - `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
   - `chown $USER:$USER ~/.ssh -R`
2. Adding more accepted public key authentication methods to the sshd config file in case that was the issue
3. Looking in logs and trying to get more information.

I saw that someone recommended looking at the logs in `/var/log/auth.log` but I could not find that, I examined the logs at `/var/log/secure` and saw only one line for the most recent failed ssh attempt:

`localhost sshd[43706]: Connection closed by authenticating user \username \ip port 11706 [preauth]`

(with \username as the linux username and \ip as the ip of the windows machine)

I also saw somewhere that issues could be caused by Windows file newline differences, so I used the tip [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79702/how-to-test-whether-a-file-uses-crlf-or-lf-without-modifying-it) and did not see any Windows newline characters at the key in `/home/andy/.ssh/authorized_keys`

What should I do/check next to figure out what's going on? I am decent at debugging/troubleshooting *nix based issues but once Windows is in the mix I am a fish out of water and not sure what to do here.

Also, just to note, I have set the config on the CentOS machine to be PublicKeyEncryption only (and would like to keep it that way) and I have also disabled root ssh (and would like to keep it that way). I have also successfully sshed into the machine on my Mac.

Comment: What do you see in the _client's_ logs?

Answer (score 1):

**client-side command & output**:

```bash
$ ssh -p 50022 andy@server
andy@server's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
andy@server's password:
```

The second password prompt also appears significantly faster than usual, almost instanteneously.

**server-side log of `sshd.service`**:

```bash
Connection closed by authenticating user andy 173.63.60.32 port 11706 [preauth]
```

(where `andy` is the user name, `173.63.60.32` the server's IP, `11706` the source port which is random)

**The problem**:

The user `andy` is not a member of its primary group on the server.

I.e.: `/etc/passwd` looks like: `andy:x:1003:1000:,,,,:/home/andy:/bin/bash` (where `1000` is the group ID)

but

`/etc/goup` looks like: `group:x:1000:user01,user02` but excludes `andy`.

**The solution**:

any of the following:

- Change `andy`s primary group to a group they are part of.
- Change `andy`s primary group to `nogroup` (gid `65534`) in `etc/passwd`: `andy:x:1003:65534:,,,,:/home/andy:/bin/bash`
- Add `andy` to their primary group.